# How to calculate the overlap / elapsed time range in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some records in ES, they are different online meeting records that people join/leave at the different time.

```
{name:"p1", join:'2017-11-17T00:01:00.293Z', leave: "2017-11-17T00:06:00.293Z"}
{name:"p2", join:'2017-11-17T00:02:00.293Z', leave: "2017-11-17T00:04:00.293Z"}
{name:"p3", join:'2017-11-17T00:03:00.293Z', leave: "2017-11-17T00:05:00.293Z"}
```

Time range could be something like this:

```
 p1: [============================================]
 p2:         [=================]
 p3:                  [==================]
```

The question is how to calculate the overlap time range (common/meeting/shared time), which should be **3 min**

Another further question is that is it possible to know when to when there is 1/2/3 people at that time? ***2 mins 2 persons; 1 min 3 persons***

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible to do only with ES. Simply because all you need is that in search it should go to all documents that matched and calculate based on that

I would do it in following steps.

1.Before indexing new document search for documents which overlaps.

```
GET /meetings/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "join": {
              "gte": "2007-10-01T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "leave": {
              "lte": "2007-10-01T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Calculate all functionality on back-end for all documents that overlaps.
3. Save to to documents as [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) overlaps metadata you need

Comment: The time range is dynamic. Could you make the schema a bit clear?

Comment: In timerange you insert value of your new meeting, to search for overlaps

Answer (score 1):

You can do the first part easily using `max(join)` and `min(leave)`:

```
GET your_index/your_type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "startTime": {
      "max": {
        "field": "join"
      }
    },
    "endTime": {
      "min": {
        "field": "leave"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can compute endTime-startTime either when you process Elasticsearch response or using a [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html). It may be negative in which case there is no overlap.

For the second one, it depends of what you want:
If you want the exact boundaries, which may be hard to read, you can do it using a [Scripted Metric Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

If you want to have the number per slot (hour for instance) it may be easier to use a [Date Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but `max()` and `min()` are not the solution, as it should be the second min to second max. And this logic does not work for meeting that happens on different days.